# How can I allow a + sign to this regex?

Tags: regex

^\d{11}$

I need to allow 10 digits and the + symbol.

Comment: Where is the + symbol allowed?  Anywhere?  Once?  Many times?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean 10 digits followed by a + sign, just use a backslash to escape the `+` sign. Example:

```
^\d{10}\+$
```

Otherwise if you need 11 characters which may be digits or the + sign, you can do:

```
^[\d+]{11}$
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape it with the `\`

```
^\d{10}\+$
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick through the use of character classes and concatenation.

```
^[0-9+]{11}$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `+` in a regular express as is, escape it with `\` - `\+` or use in a character class `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Add it to a character class if you mean you want to match the + sign anywhere, and have multiples?

`^[\d+]{11}$` matches: 123456++789

Or, you can escape it if you want it in a specific spot.  Like at the beginning followed by 10 digits

`^\+[\d]{10}$` matches: +0123456789

Your question wasn't specific enough as to what constitutes a pass and what is a fail.

Answer (score -1):

`^\d{10}\+?$`

> `^` asserts position at start of a line
> `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
> `{10}` matches the previous token exactly 10 times
> `\+` matches the character + literally (case sensitive)
> `?` matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> `$` asserts position at the end of a line
>
> Source: [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/ztwyZY/1)